# Excel 2016/365 VBA macros firing but not executing/working (Save button vs keyboard shortcut)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I have a head scratcher. One client is using Excel 2016 (16.0.9126.2259) 32bit. Office version 1803 (they're on the semi-annual update channel) which are distributed using a Managed Computer corporate infrastructure.

Snagit screen capture
https://www.screencast.com/t/BPANvVq8

You can see the video above. When I **click the Save button**, the Workbook_BeforeSave event fires fine and the code runs as expected. Part of the custom save function is to hide all but one sheet (0:10 in the video and has the company logo and says "scope"), then save the file, then re-show all the sheets. Again this works as expected. (It also creates a backup of the file using ThisWorkbook.SaveAs, which works fine)

However, when I **click Control+s keyboard shortcut** (0:23 in the video) to save the file, the Workbook_BeforeSave fires as expected and the code runs (and I can step through all the code) but nothing happens. The sheets don't hide, even though that code is executed. The file is not saved when ThisWorkbook.Save is executed. The backup file code runs but the SaveAs file is not created.

The same code works fine on my test VM machine running v1806/64bit using either the save button or keyboard shortcut. I have not spun up a 32 bit vm yet to test that.

All the VBA References are good and I don't think it's a coding issue as the macro runs fine when clicking the Save button. It just doesn't work when using the keyboard shortcut key (even though the event is firing). Very bizarre. Another user at the same client with the same computer build is experiencing the same thing.

Any ideas? I've asked that they try to roll out v1806 sooner than later but not sure how fast they'll move on that.

Comment: I once had a similar problem, but with 2010. It turned out it was caused by the *Google Drive-Plug-in für Microsoft Office* - deinstalling it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@FunThomas solved my problem in the comments:

> I once had a similar problem, but with 2010. It turned out it was
>   caused by the Google Drive-Plug-in for Microsoft Office - deinstalling
>   it solved my issue.

The Google Drive plugin was the problem and deinstalling it solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Feel free to accept this answer (even if you wrote it) if it, indeed, solved your problem. We encourage self-answers and attempts to rescue useful answers from the comments.